# What are the advantages of "yield item" vs return iter(items)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, iterator, yield

In the examples below, resp.results is an iterator.

Version1 :

```
items = []
for result in resp.results:
     item = process(result)
     items.append(item)
return iter(items)
```

Version 2:

```
for result in resp.results:
     yield process(result)
```

Is returning iter(items) in Version 1 any better/worse in terms of performance/memory savings than simply returning items?

In the "Python Cookbook," Alex says the explicit iter() is "more flexible but less often used," but what are the pros/cons of returning iter(items) vs yield as in Version 2?

Also, what are the best ways to unittest an iterator and/or yield? -- you can't do len(results) to check the size of the list?

Comment: Um.  Version 2 is shorter and doesn't create an intermediate list object.  Why wouldn't you simply use that every single time?  Why do you see these are "ambiguous" or "equivalent"?  Merely returning an iterator isn't really the issue, is it?

Comment: There is a great explanation of the yield keyword here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

Comment: Well then when would you use iter() -- As per  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/237028#237028) -- doesn't the 'for' loop automatically do 'iter(mylist)' to all lists?

Comment: S.Lott - AFAIK you can't reuse generators so iterators are more flexible.

Comment: @James why not create another generator? I do not think it's that expensive.

Comment: @James: You can't reuse iterators, either.  So in the case where you're using something more than once, neither will work.  I still don't understand the question.  Why create the intermediate object?

Comment: @S.Lott While that's technically true, you can use tee from itertools to split an iterator into two copies of itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to turn an iterator or generator back into a list if you need it:

```
results = [item for item in iterator]
```

Or as kindly pointed out in the comments, an even simpler method:

```
results = list(iterator)
```

Comment: why not just `list(iterator)`?

Comment: Thanks. That will help unittest iterators -- any tricks for unit testing yield statements?

Comment: @isakkarlsson, why not indeed? Part of the Zen of Python is supposed to be "one obvious way" for anything but I keep on getting tripped up by the exceptions.

Comment: @James, the same works for iterators or generators. In fact I keep confusing the two because they're so similar.

Answer (score 4):

The first causes all the results to be calculated and stored while the second is a lazy load, whereby the results are calculated only when requested.  That is, one will store and create a list of N items, while the other will store and create 0 items until you begin iterating through them.

A better way of thinking about this is using ifilter (from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)) wherein you are doing much the same as yield except you're generating an iterator instead of a generator:

```
 ifilter(process, resp.results)
```

I've found that iterators are generally faster executing than generators in the 2.x series but I can not verify any cost savings in the 3.x series.

Answer (score 3):

When you are processing a very large list, then `yield item` is better since it does not consume much memory.

See an excellent article in generator http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can create infinite iterators, but not infinite lists:

```
def fibGen():
    f0, f1 = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield f0
        f0, f1 = f1, f0+f1
```

Answer (score 1):

The pro *and* con of the former snippet is that all the results are calculated up front. This is useful if the time between retrieving each item is crucial, but won't do if the iterable is infinite or if space is a concern.