# Balancing memory and performance in using yield in recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, yield

I have a function that yields out permutation:

```
def all_perms(str):
    if len(str) <=1:
        yield str
    else:
        for perm in all_perms(str[1:]):
            for i in range(len(perm)+1):
                yield perm[:i] + str[0:1] + perm[i:]
```

As I understand, `yield` calculates the result on the fly instead of storing the intermediate calculates on the heap. This is good as python is [not aggressive at freeing up memory](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html). But [it takes longer to calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6231646/986067). Does it mean, it actually have to calculate entire one branch of the recursion tree every time it is called? If that is the case, time complexity of the run time will increase by N*log(N), am I right?

If indeed `yield` needs to calculate the entire one branch every time,
On every level, the calculation needs to repeat in proportion to the number of children, which adds up to N on every level. And since the depth is log(N), the total comes out to be N*log(N). This seems like too big of a trade to make. Is there a good rule of thumb when to use `yield` or a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement), you will see that `yield` freezes the state of the generator. When the control flow returns, it is as if it was an external call, so all state is kept.

So since there is no difference in runtime complexity, I would not worry too much about performance differences between lists and generators. The memory saving aspect of generators is worth considering, if you go through big collections, and the ability to create 'infinite' collections.

Also, `itertools.permutations`.